# Как сделать словарь со словами с количеством их гласных звуков из текста?

Tags: python

```
text = "These people had a little window at the back of their house from which a splendid garden could be seen, which was full of the most beautiful flowers and herbs. It was, however, surrounded by a high wal."
t = text.replace(',', '')
#print(t)
print(max(t.split(), key=len))
print(min(t.split(), key=len))
print(collections.Counter(text.split()).most_common(1))

ma_dict = {}
for word in text.split():
     ma_dict[word] = ma_dict.get(word,0)+1
     
print(ma_dict)
```

Comment: Что вы уже пытались сделать? Там же цикл в цикле, всё просто, только список всех возможных гласных заранее записать в отдельную переменную.

Comment: Ничего не делала, так как не понимаю с чего начать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш словарь уже содержит список слов в предложении. Правда последнее добавляется с точкой. Если нужно просто посчитать глассные в этих словах, то нужно добавить функцию ниже и вызвать ее. Или нужно что-то еще?

```
def vowelsearch(myDict):
        vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU' #список гласных
        for word in myDict: # для всех слов в словаре
            counter = 0 # обнуляем счетчик
            for letter in vowels: # для всех гласных
                counter += word.count(letter)  # проверяем сколько раз буква встречается в слове и прибавляем к счетчику
            myDict[word] = counter # заменяем значение в словаре
        return myDict
    
newDict = vowelsearch(ma_dict) #вызываем функцию и передаем в нее наш словарь со словами.  Она возвращает нам нужный словарь
```

Для согласных:

```
def consonantsSearch(myDict):
    consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ'  
    for word in myDict: 
        counter = 0  
        for letter in consonants:  
            counter += word.count(letter)  
        myDict[word] = counter 
    return myDict

consonantsDict = consonantsSearch(ma_dict)
```

Comment: А согласные так же само?

Comment: Можно так же. Тогда нужно вместо списка гласных, сделать список согласных. Но можно просто пройтись по словарю и отнимать от длинны слова уже посчитанные гласные. Единственный момент с последним словом. Из-за точки, его дилинна будет на 1 больше. У вас врятли скорость работы важна, так что просто замените список гласных, на список согланых. Принцип работы не изменится.  Если нужно могу написать код как искать через длинну слова.

Comment: Я сделала так же, но на выводит словарь с гласными

Comment: Без кода сложно сказать. Я добавил в ответ функцию для согласных

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "These people had a little window"

def vowelCounter(listName):
    vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, len(listName)):
        if listName[i] in vowels: count += 1
    return count

result = {}
if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = text.split(" ")
    for word in words:
        result[word] = vowelCounter(word)
    print(result)
```

Comment: А если у меня уже есть словарь, можно как то его использовать в задаче? К  примеру  import collections
text = "These people had a little window at the back of their house from which a splendid garden could be seen, which was full of the most beautiful flowers and herbs."
t = text.replace(',', '')
#print(t)
print(max(t.split(), key=len))
print(min(t.split(), key=len))
print(collections.Counter(text.split()).most_common(1))

ma_dict = {}
for word in text.split():
     ma_dict[word] = ma_dict.get(word,0)+1
     
print(ma_dict)

Comment: @Maina добавьте код в сам вопрос

Comment: Вадим, зачем вам итерация по `range(len(listName))`, вы можете итерироваться непосредственно по `listName`, вы индекс `i` сам по себе ведь не используете.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я старался кк можно проще сделать, чтобы автор понял мое решение. Как по мне это проще воспринимается

Comment: @ВадимАлександру Не понимаю, чем более сложная конструкция понятнее простой конструкции :)  Я то вам плюс поставил, но это стиль `Python 2`, так давно никто не пишет. И `range` по дефолту от нуля считает, в общем, так тоже никто не пишет.